# Add Count duplicate values in filtred array with ...new Set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array with duplicate values, i get these values from an API, the ccode below gets all the notes of **maths** without duplicate notes using the ...new Set() method :

```
let notes = [];
if (props.getAllNotes()) {
    const maths = props.getAllNotes().map(item => {
        return item.subjects[0].math_note
    });
    notes = [...new Set(maths)];
}
```

This is what i have in the **props.getAllNotes()** :

```
notes = [15,16,10,13,15,16,10,18,11,13,15,16,10,18,11];
```

And this is what i get :

```
notes = [15,16,10,13,18,11];
```

I want to add the count of each note in the final array **notes** like this for ex :

```
notes = [{10: 3}, {15: 5}...]
```

The commented method does it in object, i need to do it to the final array **notes** in which i using the **...new Set()** method because i am mapping through it to render some data

```
const counts = stars.reduce((acc, value) => ({
    ...acc,
    [value]: (acc[value] || 0) + 1
}), {});
```

Comment: `{15, 5}` isn't a valid object. What is the actual expected result?

Comment: my bad, i have updated {15: 5}

Comment: What order are you expecting in the outputted `notes` array? (why is `{10: 3}` before `{15: 5}`, is there a reason or does it not matter?)

Comment: no reason, order is not important cause Api does it

Comment: @Unmitigated can u adapt your code with item.subjects[0].math_note cause i don't see how to adapt it with your params

Comment: @Elichy Why can't you just replace `arr` in my answer with `maths`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating an object containing the frequencies of each number, you can `map` over its entries to create the desired array of objects.

```js
let arr = [15,16,10,13,15,16,10,18,11,13,15,16,10,18,11];
let res = Object.entries(arr.reduce((acc, n) => {
  acc[n] = (acc[n] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));
console.log(res);
```